# How can I optimize this Huffman code function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, huffman-code

The function's input is a dictionary like that:

```
frec = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, ... , 'c': 1}
```

And the output is the Huffman codice:

```
frec = {'a' : '00', 'b' : '01', ... , 'c': '0001'}
```

And this is the function:

```
def codice(frec):
    lista = []
    for carac,fr in frec.items():
        heappush(lista,(fr,0,carac))
    while len(lista) > 1:
        x1 = heappop(lista)    
        x2 = heappop(lista)  
        x3 = (x1[0]+x2[0],max(x1[1],x2[1])+1,[x1,x2])
        heappush(lista,x3)
    dic = {} 
    rdic = {}
    rama = [] 
    rama.append(lista[0]+('',))
    while len(rama) > 0:
        elem = rama.pop() 
        if type(elem[2]) == list:
            rama.append(elem[2][1]+(elem[-1]+'0',)) 
            rama.append(elem[2][0]+(elem[-1]+'1',))
        else:
            dic[elem[2]]=elem[-1]
            rdic[elem[-1]]=elem[2]
        pass     
    return dic,rdic
```

I was trying to use comprehension list to optimize but I'm rookie with python :). Thanks.

Comment: What are you optimizing: time, memory, or other? What kind of situation do you have in mind?

Comment: Sorry, I have to optimize time, and the situation is for long 'frec' dicts.

Comment: @JesusSono if the code works as expected (less time constraints), then you should ask on Code Review!